# R: caching/memoise for environments

Tags: r, oop, caching, memoization, proto

nI would like to use [memoization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) to cache the results of certain expensive operations so that they are not computed over and over again.

Both [memoise](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/memoise.pdf) and [R.cache](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.cache/R.cache.pdf) fit my needs. However, I am finding that caching is not robust across calls.

Here is an example that demonstrates the problem I'm seeing:

```
library(memoise)

# Memoisation works: b() is called only once
a <- function(x) runif(1)
replicate(5, a())
b <- memoise(a)
replicate(5, b())

# Memoisation fails: mfn() is called every single time
ProtoTester <- proto(
  calc = function(.) {
    fn <- function() print(runif(1))
    mfn <- memoise(fn)
    invisible(mfn())
  }      
)
replicate(5, ProtoTester$calc())
```

**Updated based on answer**

This question can have different answers based on whether persistent or non-persistent caching is used. Non-persistent caching (such as `memoise`) *may* require single assignment and then the answer below is a nice way to go. Persistent caching (such as `R.cache`) works across sessions and *should be* robust with respect to multiple assignments. The approach above works with `R.cache`. Despite the multiple assignments, `fn` is only called once with `R.cache`. It would be called twice with `memoise`.

```
> ProtoTester <- proto(
+     calc = function(.) {
+         fn <- function() print(runif(1))
+         invisible(memoizedCall(fn))
+     }      
+ )
> replicate(5, ProtoTester$calc())
[1] 0.977563
[1] 0.1279641
[1] 0.01358866
[1] 0.9993092
[1] 0.3114813
[1] 0.97756303 0.12796408 0.01358866 0.99930922 0.31148128
> ProtoTester <- proto(
+     calc = function(.) {
+         fn <- function() print(runif(1))
+         invisible(memoizedCall(fn))
+     }      
+ )
> replicate(5, ProtoTester$calc())
[1] 0.97756303 0.12796408 0.01358866 0.99930922 0.31148128
```

The reason why I thought I had a problem with `R.cache` is that I was passing a `proto` method as the function to `memoizedCall`. `proto` methods are bound to environments in ways that `R.cache` has a hard time with. What you have to do in this case is unbind the function (get from an instantiated method to a simple function) and then pass the object manually as the first argument. The following example shows how this works (both `Report` and `Report$loader` are `proto` objects:

```
# This will not memoize the call
memoizedCall(Report$loader$download_report)

# This works as intended
memoizedCall(with(Report$loader, download_report), Report$loader)
```

I'd love to know why `R.cache` works with normal functions bound to environments but fails with `proto` instantiated methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, the function is memoized anew each time it is called.
The following should work: it is only memoized once, when it is defined.

```
ProtoTester <- proto(
  calc = {
    fn <- function() print(runif(1))
    mfn <- memoise(fn)
    function(.) mfn()
  }
)
replicate(5, ProtoTester$calc())
```

Comment: I had misunderstood the object identity mechanism that the memoise implementations use. Because `R.cache` has persistence associated with memoisation I thought it is designed to work based on the content/code of the function as opposed to its internal R id or else it wouldn't work across sessions. Creating an expression with memoization as a side-effect is a nice pattern. Your code works great with `R.cache` even across assignments (executing the ProtoTester assignment multiple times which assigns `fn` multiple times). I wonder why it did not work for me before...

Comment: I checked again and found out that `R.cache` works with my old code. I must have overlooked something simple.

Comment: I updated the question and clarified the differences in behavior when persistence is involved.

Comment: I tracked down the source of the problem with R.cache and proto. R.cache seems confused by proto's instantiated methods. Unbinding them and passing the object explicitly solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to use `evals` for evaluation from (my) [pander package](http://daroczig.github.com/pander/) which has an *internal* (temporary in an environment for current R session *or* persistent with disk storage) caching engine. Short example based on your code:

```
library(pander)
ProtoTester <- proto(
  calc = function(.) {
    fn <- function() runif(1)
    mfn <- evals('fn()')[[1]]$result
    invisible(mfn)
  }      
)
```

And running `evals` with cache off and on would result in:

```
> evals.option('cache', FALSE)
> replicate(5, ProtoTester$calc())
[1] 0.7152186 0.4529955 0.4160411 0.1166872 0.8776698

> evals.option('cache', TRUE)
> evals.option('cache.time', 0)
> replicate(5, ProtoTester$calc())
[1] 0.7716874 0.7716874 0.7716874 0.7716874 0.7716874
```

Please note that the `evals.option` function si to be renamed to `evalsOption` soon to mitigate `R CMD check` warnings about S3 methods.